# Does Bell's theorem rule out the possiblity that measurements are completely determined by events in the past light cone?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, bells-inequality

I'm studying Bell's theorem and the CHSH inequality for some time. Now it's clear to me that one cannot reproduce the correlations predicted by quantum mechanics by assuming that particles carry hidden variables with them, and measurements depend only on them.

But what about the case where we consider the most general scenario: the measurement outcome can depend on the entire past light cone. Why not?

This would mean more information are available when the detector "chooses" an outcome, than just the variables carried by the current particle: for example the measurement of the current particle can depend on previous measurements, past measurements on the other detector when they reached the past light cone of the current event, etc.

Is it possible to show that such assumptions are also ruled out Bell's theorem?

Comment: Doesn't the *local* in the name of the ruled out local hidden variable theories exactly mean that hidden variables only help if they are non-local, i.e. influences can come from outside the light-cone?

Comment: @Calmarius I support ACuriousMind's answer, just I'd like to make it more explicit. Assume a measurement on two entangled particles, one coming to Alice's lab and one coming to Bob's lab. And assume that each lab is installed on another space-station. And also assume that the Alice and Bob measure at the same time by the Earth clock. From the point of view of a traveler moving toward Alice's station, Alice measures first, and Bob later. But from the point of view of a traveler moving toward Bob's station, Bob measures first, and Alice later. But the results are correlated. (I continue)

Comment: @Calmarius : then, is the result obtained by someone of the experimenters, dependent only on the past light-cone of his/her measurement, be it the *entire* light cone? ***Answer :*** entanglements work ***outside*** the space-time. Time, light-cone mean nothing to them.

Comment: All such influences are already encoded into the idea of "local hidden variables" - for instance imagine every point keeps a (hidden) memory of every event in its past light cone. Those data are still local hidden variables.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as you're assuming a local hidden variables theory it can be shown that even allowing the outcome to be determined by any arbitrary amount of prior events in the past light cone will not allow for violations of Bell inequalities. Bell demonstrates this for example in his paper "La nouvelle cuisine" which is reprinted in the collection [*Speakable and Unspeakable in Quantum Mechanics*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AKE1QYK). For a free online paper that discusses how you can include entire cross-sections of the past light cone in proofs of Bell's theorem, see ["J.S. Bell's Concept of Local Causality"](http://arxiv.org/abs/0707.0401)--note in particular Fig. 1 and Fig. 2 on page 4 of the paper, and the way equation (1) on that page defines the locality condition using the complete set of "beables" (all local variables, whether measurable or hidden variables) $B_3$ in a cross-section of the past light cone (region 3 in Fig. 2).

Comment: to be clear, if you allow the measurement choices to also correlate with the hidden variable, then Bell's theorem does not hold. In other words, in some sense, allowing correlations with arbitrary events in the past of the measurement outcomes *does* allow to violate Bell's inequalities (trivially, because in such a scenario there are no restrictions on the output probability distributions)

Comment: `trivially, because in such a scenario there are no restrictions on the output probability distributions` - never heard it put quite like this before, but this is absolutely right and one of the things I find distasteful about the idea. It doesn't specially predict what we see in these experiments, because it allows for everything, it's compatible with every possible observation anyone could make. It's solipsism for physics.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Bell's theorem (together with the Einstein-Podolsky-Rosen argument) necessarily implies that causality is nonlocal, i.e. causal connections outside the past light cone exist.  So the past light cone is not sufficient to determine all measurements.

Note that this is regardless of whether hidden variables exist or not.  This is an often-misunderstood point.  It's not, "Choose your poison: either hidden variables exist and causality is nonlocal, or hidden variables do not exist and causality is local."  It's, "Causality is nonlocal. Period."

(Note, BTW, that your statement in the first paragraph is not true:  you CAN reproduce QM correlations with a hidden variable theory, but that theory will be nonlocal.  David Bohm invented pilot wave theory to demonstrate that a hidden variable theory is capable of reproducing QM correlations.)

The logic is like this:  EPR says, in effect, "If QM is true, and causality is local, then hidden variables exist."  Bell's theorem says, "If hidden variables exist, and causality is local, then QM is false."  If the experiments demonstrate "QM is true" (as most people think they do), then those syllogisms become:  1.(EPR) If causality is local, then hidden variables exist.  2. (Bell) Either hidden variables do not exist, or causality is nonlocal.  Combining those: if causality is local, then (by EPR) hidden variables exist, so (by Bell) causality is nonlocal (contradiction).

Comment: Violations of Bell's theorem don't necessarily imply "causality is nonlocal", they just imply that the type of theories defined as "local realist" theories cannot be correct. Local realism assumes for example that each measurement yields a unique result, so if you violate that condition, you can get a theory that isn't "local realist" but features no nonlocality.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: Can you explain the difference between a local hidden variables theory and a local realistic theory?

Comment: A local hidden variables theory is just a type of local realist model, one where there are local physical variables beyond the ones that can be determined from the quantum state of a system. If quantum mechanics is correct as far as predictions of measurement results, this would imply that even if such extra variables exist they would be impossible for us to measure, hence the name "hidden".

Comment: @Hypnosifl: Bell's theorem says any local theory that is consistent with QM must be unrealistic.  EPR says any local theory that is consistent with QM must be realistic (at least w.r.t. the relevant conjugate variables).  Ergo, if the QM correlations are right, local theories are out, one way or the other.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "realistic", I don't think this term has any specific technical definition in physics apart from the overall notion of local realism. In any case, physicists who advocate the many-worlds interpretation routinely argue that it can explain EPR-type correlations in a purely local way--do you think the MWI is "realistic"?

Comment: @Hypnosifl A "realistic" theory is one in which the values of all parameters are determined with unit probability prior to any measurement of them. QM is unrealistic, which is what bothered Einstein about it and led him to think it was probably incomplete.  Hidden variables theories are the realistic alternative; they claim there are parameters that are determined, but whose values are "hidden" from QM.  In EPR/Bell discussions, then, "hidden variables" and "realistic" are almost (but not quite) interchangeable.  (cont'd...)

Comment: ... I have no idea what that says about the MWI, of which I am not a great fan.  Are causal connections from one world to another really local?

Comment: Is that your own stab at a definition, or have you seen any physicists define "realistic" this way? If "realistic" simply meant "deterministic" as you seem to suggest, then why wouldn't they use the phrase "local deterministic"? Also, if I'm not mistaken Bell's theorem is general enough to show that Bell inequalities shouldn't be violated in a local but fundamentally stochastic theory, it doesn't depend on any assumption of determinism.

Comment: As for the MWI, advocates typically argue that multiple "worlds" are not really a fundamental assumption of the model, they only emerge in an approximate way from the more fundamental perspective of a single universal wavefunction (which evolves in a completely deterministic way, so I'd think it would satisfy your definition of 'realistic' as long as you allow 'parameters' to have complex values)--see the discussion by physicist Sean Carroll [here](http://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2015/02/19/the-wrong-objections-to-the-many-worlds-interpretation-of-quantum-mechanics/) for example.

Comment: @Hypnosifl No, it's not my own definition, and no, it's not the same as determinism.  I believe you are correct that Bell's theorem does not depend on any assumption of determinism (though I'm not quite sure about that), but it does depend on the existence of the values of parameters prior to measurement (which is called "realism"), in the same sense that the EPR paper says parameters are determined prior to measurement in the entanglement experiment if one assumes local causality.

Comment: If it's not your own definition, can you point to a source that gives this definition? And doesn't "the values of all parameters are determined with unit probability prior to any measurement of them" mean the values of all parameters are completely *determined* at some time prior to the time they are measured? When you say this isn't the same as determinism, do you just mean that if the measurement is made at time t2, then there will be some prior time t1 when the values of parameters at t2 are completely determined, but at some earlier time t0 they may not be?

Comment: @Hypnosifl The condition of reality is from EPR.  But rather than getting any further off track, I would prefer to reiterate my claim: EPR points out that QM with local causality implies hidden variables in entangled states (real quantities inaccessible to QM), while Bell shows that hidden variable theories with local causality violate QM.  Assuming local causality therefore leads to a contradiction, if QM is correct. We can discuss the semantics in a more appropriate forum if you like.

Comment: As far as I can tell, EPR only say that in the specific case where variables in entangled particles are perfectly correlated (which isn't assumed in the CHSH inequality), locality demands that the values of these variables were predetermined, not that this is true in general for arbitrary variables. And "QM with local causality implies hidden variables" (the predetermined values for entangled quantities) only if you assume each local measurement has a single definite result, if you assume a superposition of different local measurement results as in the MWI, then no hidden variables are needed.